# Azure DevOps Sprint View Collapse by State

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to configure Azure DevOps Task Boards Sprint View such that it will collapse a certain state by default? The view expands New and Active states by default and collapses Completed states. I created a custom state that is categorized as Active, but want it to be collapsed when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure Azure DevOps Task Boards Sprint View such that it will collapse a certain state by default?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Azure devops does not have such settings to configure Azure DevOps Task Boards Sprint View such that it will collapse a certain state by default at this moment. You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.